# Textbook Recommendation; Proability Theory with Measure Theory

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, probability-theory

I'm currently taking a course in Probability Theory and was hoping someone could point me in the direction of a useful supplementary textbook.

Our course currently uses *A Modern Approach to Probability Theory* by Fristedt and Gray.

A link to the book is here:  [http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Approach-Probability-Theory-Applications/dp/0817638075](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817638075)

The book can be previewed here: http://books.google.com/books?id=5D5O8xyM-kMC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

The book seems clear enough (granted, through only two chapters) but leaves out many proofs and having a secondary reference to work from would be extremely helpful.

Comment: What are your background?

Comment: Undergraduate courses in Real Analysis with Rudin's book, extensive probability and statistical theory at the graduate level in a statistics department. Complex analysis, every calculus course.  Missing topology and no background whatsoever in measure theory.

Comment: Stein has a book on analysis which deals with analysis, Hilbert spaces and includes some applications to probability. Also, you might like William Feller's second book.

Answer (score 2):

You could try "Probability with Martingales" by D. Williams, ([Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Probability-Martingales-Cambridge-Mathematical-Textbooks/dp/0521406056/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1540726495&sr=8-1&keywords=+Probability+with+Martingale.)).
I think this is a pretty standard text for what you are looking to study, and certainly the one used at Cambridge University for this purpose.

Comment: See Probability and Measure course, https://www-wp.maths.cam.ac.uk/documents/coursesii.pdf/

Answer (score 0):

A really comprehensive, easy to read book is "An Introduction to measure and probability" by J.C Taylor ([Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387948309)).
Lots of examples, exercises, and really nice geometric view of conditional expectation via Hilbert spaces. All the results used are proved, so the text seems to be self contained. Also contains a chapter on martingale theory which is a nice addition.